# Is it possible to work on the same region as a locoteam but not IN the locoteam

Tags: locoteams

Was checking Jono's Site about [Ubuntu Advocacy Development Kit](http://www.jonobacon.org/2012/12/14/ubuntu-advocacy-development-kit-packaged/) and was wondering if it was possible to reach out to others in my country, state, city, community without having to be in the locoteam.

Depending on the answer, an additional question would be that if it is possible to create another locoteam.

Comment: I don't see how or why anyone would stop you. As for creating another loco, if it was a 100% overlap with an existing team I doubt you would receive approval unless there was a good reason, eg existing loco is completely inactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely! We encourage and recommend people to advocate Ubuntu either as part of a LoCo Team or outside of LoCo Teams if they wish.

The primary aim of the ADK is to simply provide all the documentation and materials you need to perform great advocacy. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a town/city that doesn't have a team, then you have the power to create one.

And, even if you're not a member of a current team, you can always reach out to someone who is by connecting to them at http://loco.ubuntu.com